# Inline code with require vs. function call

Tags: php

I wonder if I should write a function for a specific problem (e.g. `function specific()`) or if I should give this piece of code into one php script and call `require 'specific.php'` when needed?

The specific problem I'm talking is about processing a filled form requested via POST and then redirecting the browser because of the PRG (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern (which includes, that `exit` will be called and the code isn't continued after the `require` respectively function call). The code for processing the request is needed in two scripts. Consider following code:

somePage.php

```
require 'process_form_fnc.php'; // for Variant 2

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // process filled form
    require 'process_form.php'; // Variant 1
    process_form_fnc();         // or Variant 2
}
```

Would you choose the function or the require variant (and why)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `require` to insert arbitrary code blocks at the current location is a bad hackish (even though not uncommon). I would always prefer to keep my code in functions.

You can find similar discussions for C (`#include` arbitrary code snippets vs. functions), with almost the same arguments and an equally clear consensus.

Answer (score 2):

Variant 2.  Why?

- That is the whole purpose of functions.
- A function can have argument(s), and a return value.
- A function has its own scope, so it cannot interfere with the caller scope.

Comment: include and require actually do return values as well (which should not smaller your argument).

Answer (score 1):

The use of includes should generally only occur for a couple of reasons:

1) You have a **generic** or **multi-use** code fragment that you would use on multiple pages

2) You would like to abstract certain portions of code out to a sort of "library"-like container/directory for organization purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I rarely if ever directly use include/require.  Most of my work is done with classes, and i use __AUTOLOAD to load it.  Personally I would use the variant 2, because you run into this issue

```
$var = "test";
include "test.php";
$var = "test2";
include "test".php";
```

could result with errors if you define a function in there, say for sorting purposes.  You'd get a duplicate declaration.  if it was a function()

```
include "test.php";
outputTest("test");
outputTest("test2");
```

and as long as you don't define a function in that function, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The function would be my preference for several reasons, one of the main being scoping of variables.

Imagine the situation where you use "require", then somewhere down the road you edit the required code to include a new variable that conflicts with a variable elsewhere in your code.

Imagine you use a quick little generic variable like $x or $i you could create intermittent nightmarish bugs that would be a real headache to track down.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be placed in a function or method so that it may have its own variable scope, and not cloud up the global namespace. I would prefer that it be held in a method of a class however. This way I could use a class autoloader to only load the contained code when it is actually being used, as well as further clear up the global namespace.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php